# Recycleview seem to cut root layout with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I tried a great lib: https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android

This lib works very well used in a single layout. Also in `ListView`, there is no problem. Animation is fast and correct. During animation, the item layout give to user an experience of 3D effect. So in this short time layout width become larger and return to default width in the second part of animation.

I tried in `RecyclerView`, and animation is fast but I noticed an issue. The animation have not any more 3D effect. So layout width has the same size during all animation. I did search for custom field to put in xml or something else, but without results.

Answer (score 0):

This is an already reported problem of the library and you should ask the mantainer to solve it.
Link to the issue on github: https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android/issues/9

Comment: I opened that issue on github. But maybe the problem is general and not of that lib

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that.